# Removed Hidden DOM element in post request javascript

Tags: javascript, html, post

I have a form with a checkbox, it has a hidden element so that if the user leaves it unchecked the post request will send with it Form item: "Item name" = "" (blank)

But if the checkbox is checked, it will send Form item: "Item name" = "Yes"

```
<input id="fieldX" name="Item Name" type="checkbox" value="Yes" class=""  >
<input id="fieldHidden" name="Item Name" type="hidden" value="" class=""  >
```

I use JS to "disable" the hidden dom element if it is left blank

```
if(document.getElementById('fieldX').checked) {
document.getElementById('fieldHidden').disabled = true; };
```

Everything works fine when the checkbox is left blank.

But when i use wireshark to analyze the post packet when the checkbox is checked it is sending both inputs in the post request.

Any ideas how i can use javascript to remove the hidden dom element from the post request if the checkbox is checked?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Disable the hidden input when the checkbox is checked and enable when unchecked. For handling this use a change event handler.

```
document.getElementById('fieldX').addEventListener('change', function() {
   document.getElementById('fieldHidden').disabled = this.checked; 
});
```

Comment: Sorry are you saying that the inputs cannot have the same name? If i am wrong i apologize i am very new to JS. The reason being the form handler on the other side needs to be able to take that specific field as either empty or Yes (hence why they have the same name)

Comment: @SpaceTime : I just updated my answer...... please add the script at the end of your code and try....